# Linux dynamic SCSI device naming

Tags: linux, scsi

When linux boots up, it assigns SCSI drives to various `sd*` names, in increasing alphabetical order. If I remove some drives (while the system is running) and re-add them, is it guaranteed that the old `sd*` names will be reused? Or will it just continue from the last name?

In other words, say I have `sda`, `sdb`, and `sdc` on my system, and I remove the drive corresponding to `sdb`. If I re-add it (or add a different drive, for that matter), will linux always reuse `sdb` for that drive? Or could it assign it to e.g. `sdd`?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not guaranteed.

I don't know the internals, but if you hot-swap a drive, it usually gets the next highest unused drive name. Sometimes, when you hot-swap the drive that used to use the highest drive name, it will reuse the old name.

I would suggest [using UUID to identify the drives](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID), as it always remains the same for a single drive.

Comment: I'd like to use UUIDs, but for my particular use case, I identify by the `sd*` name.